# Windows Phone application link to the store

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to add "Share App" button in About page of my application. To do this I need application link in marketplace.

```
  ShareLinkTask shl = new ShareLinkTask();
  shl.LinkUri = new Uri(URI_OF_APP_IN_MARKETPLACE, UriKind.Absolute);
  shl.Message = "Message";
  shl.Title = "Title";
  shl.Show();
```

Now this application is published already in the marketplace. I can get link from here also from dev.windowsphone.com also.

[image]

I can use this link also. But will be it changed after updating application? Or is there anyway to get link from code behind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it'll stay the same, even for future versions.

You can always use the `appId` and `MarketplaceDetailTask` to get more details about your app. Or even `MarketplaceSearchTask`, depending on what you want to do.

Providing that link alone should be enough for your purpose.

[Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: But, isn't there anyway to get it from code-behind? For example, if i want to get it from the first time? I mean before publishing the application for the first time?

Comment: Please see the link provided, you can use various types of Tasks available.